# How can I connect to an MDB file (Access database) in .NET4.5.1?

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.5, visual-studio-2013

I've added an MDB table to my ASP.NET WebAPI project's App_Data folder.

But as this seems such an odd thing to do (I guess that's the reason), I can't find any examples on how to make the programmatic connection. Does anybody have any sample code for that?

### UPDATE

I tried this:

```
using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\PlatypusBill\Data\PlatypusDAT03.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;"))
using (var comm = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM HERE2ETERNITY WHERE B = FinaleOfSeem";
    comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    conn.Open();
    var returnValue = comm.ExecuteScalar(); // <-- fails here with "The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error."
}
```

...but as the comment shows, I get an error.

### UPDATE 2

It runs now, with this code:

```
using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;User ID=poisonousSpur;Password=venomousSpur;Data Source=C:\PlatypusBill\DATA\PlatypusDAT01.MDB;Persist Security Info=False;Jet OLEDB:System database=C:\PlatypusBill\Data\duckbill.mdw"))
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM duckbilled_platypi";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    conn.Open();
    var returnValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    if (returnValue != null)
    {
        string s = returnValue.ToString();
        Add(new Platypus { Id = 77, DuckbillId = s, DuckbillName = s });
    }
}
```

But returnValue == 0, although I can run the same query in Access and it returns the expected (non-0) value.

### UPDATE 3

I don't know why it would make a difference, but I switched to a different "version" of the database (from DB1 to DB3), and now it works. BOTH of them work the same directly in Access - I can see the data, query it, etc.; so why it makes a difference to my project, I don't know. But at least it's working now.

### UPDATE 4

It stopped working again today, giving me that same err msg ("The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error"), and this time changing "Persist Security Info=False" to "Persist Security Info=True" in the connection string solved it.

Comment: The `conn.Open()` is apparently not tanking, so it looks like the database connection is being established. Can you try a super-simple SQL statement like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableName` and see if `.ExecuteScalar()` returns a good old `Int32` value?

Comment: Okay, I tried the simplest possible SQL statement, and I still get that err msg; as you noticed, the Open() works, but the ExecuteScalar() does not...weird...

Comment: If FinaleOfSeem is a string then it needs to be surrounded in apostrophes, if it is, more likely, a variable then it needs to be taken outside of the sql and concatenated to it. I'm hoping also that your field is not actually named 'B'!

Comment: If I run the query in Access, it returns the number I would expect.

Comment: @AndyG: No, that's a bogus SQL statement; I just didn't want to give the real table name; some employers are "paranoid" that-a-way. It's really now (for testing): SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Bla (where "Bla" is the table name). BTW, you're not the Andy G I know from Wisconsin, are you?

Comment: Re: @AndyG - Seeing as his [profile page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/620444/andy-g) says that he's from the UK, probably not. ;)

Comment: No, sorry :) I have an Aunt in Wisconsin.. but that's not the same ;). You could try "SELECT 1" but I suspect it is a permissions issue.

Comment: @AndyG re: permissions - Certainly worth investigating.

Comment: Very likely it is permissions, as I'm not adding a password in my connection string. But wouldn't that fail on the Open()? I am able to open the tables from the desktop in Access without supplying a password...

Comment: I thought UK stood for Upper Kaukauna, which is Wisconsin.